# Unable to cover or conditioned line in test case

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, testcase, test-coverage

I am one function where I am returning values like this...

```
GetData(){
let parsedData= JSON.parse(data.data.json);
        return {
            x: parsedData.x|| [],
            y: parsedData.y|| []
        };
}
```

I wrote 4 test case to cover this return response line.

```
1. x with 1 and y with 0 length 
 2. x with 1 and y with 1 length  
 3. x with 0  and y with 0 length
 4. x with 0 and y with 1 length
```

But I am still unable to cover these two lines in testcase

```
return {
            x: parsedData.x|| [],
            y: parsedData.y|| []
        };
```

any suggestion on this ?

Comment: What does not work ? `0` is `falsey` value...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly,  then you should check for `undefined`

You can do

```
GetData(){
    let parsedData= JSON.parse(data.data.json);
    return {
        x: typeof parsedData.x !== 'undefined' ? parsedData.x : [],
        y: typeof parsedData.y !== 'undefined' ? parsedData.y : []
    };
}
```